# Left join where left table column = something or null

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join a left table with the right table, and keep all left table rows even if right table does not have a match. ... a standard left join.

Include only left table rows meeting a criteria.

Include only right table rows meeting a criteria. If none is found, use null in the join.

Sort by column in right table, if not null, but don't loose entry if null.

in psudo sql, I want

```
(
    select
        *
    from
        work_item
    where
        work_item.id_work_item_queue = 5
) as t1

(
    select
        *
    from
        ai_guess
    where
        ai_guess.AI_Guess_Date = '2019:08:09:19:49:02'
) as t2

select
    t1.*,
    t2.*
from 
    t1
    left join t2 on t1.id_word_crop = t2.id_word_crop
ORDER BY
    ai_guess.text
```

The closes I come to a solution is

```
SELECT 
    work_item.id_work_item,
    work_item.id_word_crop,
    ai_guess.text

FROM
    work_item
    LEFT JOIN ai_guess ON
    work_item.id_word_crop = ai_guess.id_word_crop

WHERE
    work_item.id_work_item_queue = 5
    AND
    ai_guess.AI_Guess_Date = '2019:08:09:19:49:02'

ORDER BY
    ai_guess.text
```

This generates

```
id_work_item, id_word_crop, text
'4', '224343', 'eie'
'3', '224342', 'geüichrt'
'2', '224341', 'rschaunig'
'6', '224345', 'VSnge'
```

but it's missing and entry from the left table

```
id_work_item, id_word_crop
'5', '224344'
```

The left table contains

```
SELECT
    id_work_item,
    id_word_crop
FROM
    work_item
where
    id_work_item_queue = 5
```

```
    id_work_item, id_word_crop
    '2', '224341'
    '3', '224342'
    '4', '224343'
    '5', '224344'
    '6', '224345'
```

The right table does not have a match so the left entry is dropped but I want to keep the left entry.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ai_guess
where
    id_word_crop = 224344
```

returns null

Comment: Have you tried `RIGHT JOIN ai_guess` instead of `LEFT JOIN ai_guess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the criteria on the `ai_guess` table from the `WHERE` to `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    work_item.id_work_item,
    work_item.id_word_crop,
    ai_guess.text
FROM work_item
LEFT JOIN ai_guess
    ON work_item.id_word_crop = ai_guess.id_word_crop AND
       ai_guess.AI_Guess_Date = '2019:08:09:19:49:02'
WHERE
    work_item.id_work_item_queue = 5
ORDER BY
    ai_guess.text;
```

What is happening now is that the join generates the intermediate result you want, but then the `WHERE` clause is filtering off the missing record because its guess date does not match.  By placing this restriction in the join criteria it prevents that record from being removed prematurely.